# How can I build a Views with oEmbed Vimeo Thumbnails?

Tags: views, media

I have a content type that I'm using [Media oEmbed](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_oembed) and [Media Vimeo](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_vimeo) to display and play videos in. What I want to do with the [Views Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) is create a View Page that shows the thumbnails of the video and uses the thumbnail to link the node.

The thumbnails are being uploaded into the public files through the embed process with the filename matching the Vimeo video ID, but I can't figure out what field to use or replacement sting to grab that Vimeo ID.

I have the videos in the content type, I have the thumbnails being stored locally on my server in my public files, I just don't know how to bring them all together with Views.

Comment: are these thumbnails accessible via content type's field?

Comment: Nope. They are not.

Comment: I'm Afraid you might need to make them.

Comment: @Molot I was surprised they weren't. Through the embed flow, it's obviously grabbing and downloading the thumbnails to the server so I figured it would be accessible through the field. Any idea how I can make them?

Comment: Sorry. If I knew, I would answer. I commented because I hoped it might be a helpful hint for someone, but that's all I can do at the moment :(